# Processor architecture question

Tags: wine, cpu, architecture

i want to install Wine and during the tutorial i have seen this code `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` which is enabling 32-bit architecture. I have a 64-bit computer, with Intel i3, and I'm asking if I can reverse this, like from 32-bit to get back on 64-bit, or have something like x86-x64. Besides this, can someone explain me, or give me links to read about how does architectures works? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Architecture - 32-bit handling 64-bit instructions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/410278/architecture-32-bit-handling-64-bit-instructions)

Comment: That commands adds support for 32bit. It doesn't change it to 32bit.